# How to retrieve specific elements from a namespaced xml using xPath

Tags: xml, vb.net, namespaces

I have a question regarding retrieving nodes from a namespaced xml. As long as I specify a single element of the xml in my query I can retrieve all matching elements and I can iterate through their children. My problem arises when I try to retrieve a single unique element by specifying a more detailed query.

XML FILE I AM USING FOR TESTING

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<<MTConnectStreams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mtconnect.org:MTConnectStreams:1.2 http://mtconnect.org/schemas/MTConnectStreams_1.2.xsd" xmlns="urn:mtconnect.org:MTConnectStreams:1.2">
  <Streams>
    <Samples>
      <Position dataItemId="xs4" timestamp="2012-11-29T12:30:19Z" sequence="1718269" name="x_pos_cmd" subType="COMMANDED" units="MILLIMETER">1</Position>
      <Position dataItemId="xs5" timestamp="2012-11-29T12:30:19Z" sequence="1718270" name="x_pos_act" subType="ACTUAL" units="MILLIMETER">2</Position>
      <Position dataItemId="xs4" timestamp="2012-11-29T12:30:19Z" sequence="1718269" name="y_pos_cmd" subType="COMMANDED" units="MILLIMETER">3</Position>
      <Position dataItemId="xs4" timestamp="2012-11-29T12:30:19Z" sequence="1718269" name="y_pos_act" subType="COMMANDED" units="MILLIMETER">4</Position>
      <Position dataItemId="xs4" timestamp="2012-11-29T12:30:19Z" sequence="1718269" name="z_pos_cmd" subType="COMMANDED" units="MILLIMETER">5</Position>
    </Samples>
    <Condition>
      <Unavailable dataItemId="xc1" type="POSITION" timestamp="2012-11-27T23:19:40Z" sequence="7" name="x_cond_pos">UNAVAILABLE</Unavailable>
      <Unavailable dataItemId="xc2" type="LOAD" timestamp="2012-11-27T23:19:40Z" sequence="8" name="x_cond_load">UNAVAILABLE</Unavailable>
    </Condition>
  </Streams>
</MTConnectStreams>
```

Given the following code:

```
Dim xIt As XPathNodeIterator
Dim xDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
xDoc.Load("c:\Download\Test.xml")
Dim xNav As XPathNavigator = xDoc.CreateNavigator
Dim nsMgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(xNav.NameTable)
nsMgr.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:mtconnect.org:MTConnectStreams:1.2")

sQuery = "//ns:Samples"
xIt = xNav.Select(sQuery, nsMgr)
MsgBox(xIt.Count.ToString)

When sQuery = "//ns:Samples" (1 result)
When sQuery = "//ns:Position" (5 results)
When sQuery = "//ns:Samples/Position (0 results  why?)
When sQuery = "//ns:Samples/Position[@name='x_pos_act'] (0 results)
When sQuery = "//ns:Position[@name='x_pos_act']" (0 results)
When sQuery = "//ns:Position/[@name='x_pos_act']" (0 results)
```

etc etc. Whenever the query is more than a single node name I get no results. I cannot figure out how to specify more detailed queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work using `//ns:Samples/ns:Position`

Afaik in XPath you have to specify the namespace prefix in each subpart. This also applies to attributes!

So try:

```
When sQuery = "//ns:Samples"
When sQuery = "//ns:Position"
When sQuery = "//ns:Samples/ns:Position
When sQuery = "//ns:Samples/ns:Position[@ns:name='x_pos_act']
When sQuery = "//ns:Position[@ns:name='x_pos_act']"
When sQuery = "//ns:Position/[@ns:name='x_pos_act']"
```

If you don't want to consider namespaces you can also use the `@*[local-name()='Samples']` syntax. This will ignore all namespaces and only check the node name itself.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. Strange to have to repeatedly specify the namespace. Seems like you should be able to do something like just set the namespace you want to deal with in a property of your navigator or iterator object and it would assume that is the namespace you mean. Anyway, thanks again for your help.